# How to return complete html of a page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I return complete html of a page using jQuery?

I cannot do

```
return $('html').html()
```

or

```
return "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
```

because the page might not have html tag in it at all. I cannot use a class or id tag because this is not something that I control and can change. So the use case is if I pass a url I need to return complete html of the page and the page may or may not have html tagin it.

Comment: test that whatever you do is cross-browser. I remember doing something once and found out the elements in `<head>` are not reported consistently among browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, `$("html")` will return an element in all sane situations, even if the source document didn't contain an `<html>` element. This is because the browser will automatically insert certain required elements (including `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>`) into the DOM tree, even if they were not specified in the source document.

The only exception I can think of (where you wouldn't get anything from `$("html")`) would be if you were running JQuery against a DOM tree that isn't HTML -- for instance, if you load JQuery into an SVG document. You'd be crazy to do that, though. :)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try:

```
$(document).html();
```

Edit: This doesn't work for me in Firebug, so I am not sure if it will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

---

For older Firefox, you'll need to use `.innerHTML` instead, and then concatenate the `<html>` tags.

---

> *"the page might not have html tag in it at all"*

If you don't have `<html>` tags, the browser will insert them automatically. If you want an exact representation of the original document, make an AJAx request, as suggested by @Rab Nawaz